# Google DataStream not connecting to Google CloudSQL instance

Tags: google-datastream

I am setting up Google DataStream and connecting to a Google CloudSQL database. The DataStream requires IP address, port, username and pw to connect to the db. I am supplying the correct information. The db and DataStream are on the same VPC network (10.0.4.0/24, 10.0.5.0/24 and 10.0.0.0/24 respectively). On the DataStream setup wizard, there is a button to test the connection. I click the button and eventually get a message stating that the test has timed out. There is no further error. I CAN connect to the db from a Google VM, on the same network, so I know the networking and credentials work.

I have reviewed several troubleshooting documents and they tell me to go back and check the settings and network. I'm not sure why the connection test isn't working.